# Infinite number of Unramified Holomorphic maps on the complex Torus

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I am trying to an exercise that goes like this:

> Show that there are an infinite number of Unramified Holomorphic maps $F:\mathbb{C}/L \rightarrow\mathbb{C}/L  $ that are not automorphisms.

Well we know that for the map not to be an automorphism its degree cannot be $1$, but locally at any point it has to look like $z$, so we need maps that are not injective but somehow behave nicely in local coordinates, and i cant come up with any , any tips or advice is appreciated. Also i read that if we consider the lattice $L=\mathbb{Z}+\gamma\mathbb{Z}, Im(\gamma)>0 $ , then its degree $d$ will be a square and i cant seem to see this too.Thanks in advance.

Comment: By Hurwitz formula, any (nonconstant) holomorphic map between complex toruses is unramified (and by Liouville, it is easy to show that they all lift to affine maps $G(z)=\gamma z+\alpha$ on the plane) so you just need to find $\gamma L \subset L, \gamma L \ne L$ and $\gamma z$ will descend to an unramified map of degree $[L:\gamma L]$ on the torus

Comment: Yeah that makes sense but still havent been able to see that the degree is that , im trying to see for the point $[0]$.

Comment: try for a simple lattice like $\mathbb Z+\mathbb Z[i]$ and $\gamma =2$ and see that for example $2\frac{1}{2}=0, 2\frac{i}{2}=0, 2\frac{1+i}{2}=0$ so $0$ has $4$ preimages, so the degree is $4$ - and the map around each preimage is locally injective

Comment: Hm ok to prove that thats the degree i created a bijection between $F^{-1}(0)$ and $[L:\gamma L]$ where it sends $z$ to $\gamma z$ , and in the other direction it send $[l]$ to $l/\lambda$, dont know if there is another better way to think about this.

Comment: Also do you have any idea about the statement that the degree has to be a square? @Conrad

Comment: think of the integer case when $\gamma=c$ positive integer; then $a\omega_1+b\omega_2, 0 \le a,b \le c-1$ are distinct elements in $[L:cL]$ (so descend to distinct elements in the LHS of the map) and they all map to zero under $F$ so the fiber of zero has $c^2$ elements, hence the degree is $c^2$; then  think how this example generalizes to arbitrary complex $\gamma L \subset L$ where now $\gamma \omega_1=a_1\omega-1+b_1\omega_2, a_1,b_1 \in \mathbb Z$ and same for $\gamma \omega_2$